# what is debug mode and how do i turn it on using jboss in windows command console?

Tags: debugging, command-line, jboss

I would like to know what is debug mode in jboss. I've used django before and when I turned on  debug mode, any change I make while the localhost is running will be detected and refreshing the page will show the changes. Is that the same in jboss debug?

I use maven to install the project then start jboss in windows command console. How do I turn on debug mode for jboss 5.1.1?

Maven clean install takes about 8 minutes, then restarting the server is another 5-7 minutes. I am wasting a lot of time for many small changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable remote debugging on the JVM allowing you to connect via your IDE and you can from there run your app in bebug (stop the execution and go step by step).  Look on the statup script, the remote debug option has been put in comment.  Debug allow you to update some class (you need to connect the IDE to it and update your class via the IDE, the JVM and JBOSS won't detect the change them self).  But if you update any container managed part (EJB, persistance context, servlet) you will need to redeploy the application.  So I don't think it will give you what you need.

Why do you do a clean install each time?  A simple install should create your package and prevent any compilation, file copy if the source is older than the build artifact.  You can also redeploy your application without shutting down JBoss.  There is Maven goal for that.  By default I think, if JBoss detect that the application file (ear or war) has been change (the timestamp is lower than deploy time) it will redeploy the application (some time redeploy is unfortunately not enough, most of the time class loader issue.  Never get issue with JBoss as 7 but class loading has been redone).

If you can upgrade to JBoss AS 7, it is far quicker and Java EE 6 make your application lighter impacting positively the build time.  But this may require to much refactoring.

Comment: also, most of the time i reinstall is due to js problems which sometimes intellij just dont detect that well. so if i turn on the debug mode then the js changes will show if just refresh the page right>